# Fetch values from spark dataframes with alias

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I joined to tables and this is the result:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| Pk1| Pk2|Col2|Col3| Pk1| Pk3|Col1|Col3|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
|   a|null|   1|   d|null|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|   a|null|   1|   g|
|   b|   1|   2|   c|   b|   1|null|null|
|   c|   1|null|   o|   c|   1|   3|   s|
|   d|   1|   4|   n|   d|   1|null|   t|
|   d|   1|   4|   n|   d|   1|   4|   n|
|   e|   1|   4|   i|null|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|null|   z|   1|null|   i|
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+

 val join = source.alias("s").join(target.alias("t"), source(Pk1) === target(Pk1) && source(Pk2) === target(Pk3), "full")

join.collect().head.getAs[Any]("s.Pk1")
```

I want to fetch values with duplicate column name and the alias doesn't work for me. What else can I do to get the values?

The error:

```
s.Pk1 does not exist. Available: Pk1, Pk2, Col2, Col3, Pk1, Pk3, Col1, Col3
```

Answer (score 1):

The how is to use the plan outputs for source's pk1:

```scala
    val source = sourceSeq.toDS()
    val target = targetSeq.toDS()
    val joined = source.join(target, source("Pk1") === target("Pk1") && source("Pk2") === target("Pk3"), "full")

    val found =
      for {
        sourceFound <- joined.queryExecution.analyzed.output.find { at => at.name == "Pk1" }
        joinedFound <- joined.queryExecution.analyzed.output.zipWithIndex.find { case (at, _) => at == sourceFound }
        ind = joinedFound._2
      } yield ind

    val sourcePk1 = joined.collect().head.getAs[Any](found.get)
    println(sourcePk1)
```

This works because the AttributeReferences are unique within the plan, they just are thrown away for the simple name in the output. The alias function only helps when using sql to join, in your code you are using the source dataset directly to access the column, so it's the right one used.

As to whether this is a good idea or not.. The contents and accessibility of queryExecution can vary between releases and it's not exactly a user interface.  You are probably better off renaming the fields directly:

```scala
    
    def prefixFields[T](ds: Dataset[T], prefix: String): DataFrame = {
      val newNames = ds.schema.fieldNames.map(o => col(o).as(prefix + o))
      ds.select(newNames : _*)
    }

    // prefixing with s. _may_ work, but .'s have specific meaning
    val source = prefixFields(sourceSeq.toDS(), "source_")
    val target = targetSeq.toDS()
    val joined = source.join(target, col("source_Pk1") === target("Pk1") && col("source_Pk2") === target("Pk3"), "full")

    joined.show()
    val sourcePk1 = joined.collect().head.getAs[Any]("source_Pk1")
    println(sourcePk1)
```

It's less internal magic and a bit clearer as to intent.